# How to add a:hover color to AMP dropdown menu

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, hover

I just switched my site over to AMP using the free theme. I added the drop-down menu CSS code that scrolls and works well but I cannot figure out how to add the a:hover background color #cc3333 or isolate which element it should point to. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

https://partyfavorz.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add this code to your css.

```
.amp-menu>li a:hover{
    background: #cc3333;
}
```

Comment: Perfect! I was on the right track and was using a combination of elements. Thanks much.